# The normalizer problem for group rings

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-rings

I recently studied about The Normalizer problem (NP) which states that given an integral group ring $\Bbb{Z}G$, $N_{\cal{U}}(G)=G\frak{z}$ where $\frak{z}$ denotes centre of $\cal{U}$ = $\cal{U}$$(\Bbb{Z}G)$.

I found that this has been proved for finite nilpotent groups , groups of odd order and for groups having a normal sylow 2-subgroup i.e. $2$-closed groups

[Jesper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869301987241) proved it for locally nilpotent groups and F.C. groups with commutator a $p$- group. This paper was received in 2000

Then there is one by [Labao](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/AGB-120021903?journalCode=lagb20#.VlQhhOLpUhQ) which proves it for complete monomial groups. This paper was received in 2001

What are some other groups or classes of groups for which  this problem has been established? What is the latest work done on NP and current status of problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I would call the normalizer problem a conjecture. There is a famous counter-example by Hertweck: Theorem A in http://www.jstor.org/stable/3062112  That paper also contains a short review of previous work on the problem (of course only up to 2001).